# How I should reference Custom Control in C# code behind file event trigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces, custom-controls

In Xaml page I reference my custom control this way:

```
<MyNamespace:CustControl x:Name="Cust1" />
```

Now I want change the property of this custom control in MouseLeftButtonDown event trigger:

```
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But when I try to write something like

```
CustControl.IsSelected = true;
```

An error says: An object reference is required ..

I think it's all about "MyNamespace" namespace, but don't know how to reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be referencing Cust1, but sometimes Visual Studio does not immediately create a field member for the control. Try typing Cust1.IsSelected and even if Visual Studio doesn't like it, try building to see if it succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

The x:Name is "Cust1", so you would refer to it as Cust1:

```
Cust1.IsSelected = true;
```

I.e. Cust1 is the name of the *instance*; CustControl is the name of the *type*.

Answer (score 3):

`CustControl` is the name of the class; `Cust1` is the name of the instance.

Try `Cust1.IsSelected = true`.

Answer (score 2):

You would reference is as "Cust1", not its type.

```
Cust1.IsSelected = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

> Cust1.IsSelected = true;

where "Cust1" is the Name property of the control

If WPF & asp.net work the same way "CustControl" is the name of the class, "Cust1" is the instance.